# Unable to renew a .su domain

Tags: domains, domain-registrar, cctld

I've just purchased a **.su** domain on RU-CENTER (established by the Russian Institute for Public Networks, RIPN). It seems that there is no way to renew domain names. When I click **Renewal** as shown the figure below,

[image]

It reminds me `Services for renewal not found`

[image]

I didn't find the auto-renew service as well. How do I renew my domain?

Comment: https://www.nic.ru/dns/service/en/how-prolong.html

Comment: @SimonHayter,  When I click **Renewal**, it reminds me **Services for renewal not found**.

Comment: Then sorry but you need to contact them since its there website which is broken.

Comment: @SimonHayter, the only way contacting them is via phone, no email:-(

Comment: @sparkandshine then you have to phone them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not renew this domain name so soon.
See https://www.nic.ru/dns/service/prolong/en/detailed_description.html#ru (this applies to SU too, see header in webpage) :

> The Customer can also renew the service before the indicated term (but not earlier than 2 months before the service expiration date).